# How to convert this non-JSON string to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I’m getting this String from Firebase:

```js
"[{type:'salad', qt:0, price:0.25},{type:'cheese', qt:0, price:0.45},{type:'bacon', qt:0, price:0.75},{type:'meat', qt:0, price:4.00},]"
```

It’s a string that, if evaluated as JavaScript, would result in an array of objects. I need to convert it to a proper array of objects, using JavaScript. The expected result is this array:

```js
[
  { type: 'salad', qt: 0, price: 0.25 },
  { type: 'cheese', qt: 0, price: 0.45 },
  { type: 'bacon', qt: 0, price: 0.75 },
  { type: 'meat', qt: 0, price: 4.00 }
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Where does that string come from? If it was JSON you could just use `JSON.parse`, but that particular string isn't valid JSON. There's no way to do this without some ugly string parsing/transformation - I would prefer to solve the problem at the point the data is saved to the database.

Comment: Agreed. The fact that you have that string means something has gone wrong earlier on, either in your request on on the server side.

Comment: I sent the array to Firebase Realtime Database. But it converts to strings in the response. When I do it with Java, I use Gson to convert it back to the format sent in the first place. But with javascript I dont know if there's a library like Gson.

Comment: please visit my updated answer below. Furthermore if you are doing it through form of some sort then please try setting the xhr.response =''json" etc it will save you the whole mess as it parses string when it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although fixing the saved data is the best bet, this will work but its very "hacky".

Simply replace all of the keys with strings wrapped in double quotes and replace the single quotes with double quotes then use `JSON.parse`

```js
str = "[{type:'salad', qt:0, price:0.25},{type:'cheese', qt:0, price:0.45},{type:'bacon', qt:0, price:0.75},{type:'meat', qt:0, price:4.00},]"

str = str.replace(/'/g, '"');
str = str.replace(/type/g, '"type"');
str = str.replace(/qt/g, '"qt"');
str = str.replace(/price/g, '"price"');

str = str.replace(",]","]")

arry = JSON.parse(str)

console.log(arry)
```

Comment: The data sent is an Array of objects. But Firebase converts it to string. Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way to save to Firebase as Array?

Comment: @EiteWald, the problem is how Firebase converts it. Can you save it as a JSON instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
const fireStr = "[{type:'salad', qt:0, price:0.25},{type:'cheese', qt:0, price:0.45},{type:'bacon', qt:0, price:0.75},{type:'meat', qt:0, price:4.00},]";

const stringCorrection = str => {
  str = str.replace(/,(?=(\]|\})$)/gmui, '');
  str = str.replace(/'/gmui, '');
  
  [...new Set(str.match(/[a-z]+/gmui))].forEach(el => {
    const reg = new RegExp(`${el}`, 'g', 'i');

    const str2 = `"${el}"`;

    str = str.replace(reg, str2);
  });


  return str;
}

const str = stringCorrection(fireStr);

const myArr = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(myArr);
```

Result:

```
[
  { type: 'salad', qt: 0, price: 0.25 },
  { type: 'cheese', qt: 0, price: 0.45 },
  { type: 'bacon', qt: 0, price: 0.75 },
  { type: 'meat', qt: 0, price: 4 }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on comments and since whole thing goes south and since no one has come up with the answer as yet. here is the final solution.
Keeping in mind string it self is not valid json this is where the problem rests.

```js
    var abc = "[{type:'salad', qt:0, price:0.25},{type:'cheese', qt:0, price:0.45},{type:'bacon', qt:0, price:0.75},{type:'meat', qt:0, price:4.00},]".replace(/\[|\]/gi, "").replace(/\},\{/gi, '}|{').split('|');

    //remove all the chunks and prepare for pre-processing



    //a function that takes the whole pre-processing string and converts into  valid json

    function makeitright(a){


     var jsonStrig = '[{';
              var items = a.replace(/\{|\}|'/gi, "").split(',');
              for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                  var current = items[i].split(':');
                  jsonStrig += '"' + current[0] + '":"' + current[1] + '",';
              }
              jsonStrig = jsonStrig.substr(0, jsonStrig.length - 1);
              jsonStrig += '}]';
    return JSON.parse(jsonStrig)[0];

    }

    //runs everything ina loop to give you teh array as desired.

    final = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++){
    final.push(makeitright(abc[i]));
    }
    console.log(final[1].type);
```

This based on current question and string as stated in example string. If it had been valid json to begin with I would have stood with my previous answer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: 0


I’m getting this String from Firebase:

"[{type:'salad', qt:0, price:0.25},{type:'cheese', qt:0, price:0.45},{type:'bacon', qt:0, price:0.75},{type:'meat', qt:0, price:4.00},]" 
I believe they did state that and for all clarity sake all they need to to do is associate it to some other variable as in my case var abc and call it from there ...it is simple

Comment: "it does not need any additional parsing on client side" You have to parse somewhere client side. This is nonsense.

Comment: @user4642212 please revisit my updated answer for current situation and question. and if found worthy enough please update to upvote.

Comment: @user4642212 setting responseType = 'json'; on ajax call really helps achieve as I had stated with my previous answer. I guess consideration was not taken that string it self was not valid json. Other wise i dont even bother parsing json  explicitly.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your input. I appreciated it.

Comment: @EiteWald welcome and if answer is of any help please be kind enough to up vote .